# Printing all columns from "Select *" query in java

Tags: java, sql

I want to know how to print "Select *" query in java ? I tried this function but it give me this message "invalid column name "after execution.

```
public static void ask() throws Exception {
    try {
        java.sql.Statement s= conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DB1.T1");

        System.out.println("**************Resultats**************");
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            String all = rs.getString("*");
            System.out.println(all);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to print the query itself or the result of this query?

Comment: try rs.getString(1);try rs.getString(2)

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827735/java-resultset-getstringcol-name-query

rs.getString(1);try rs.getString(2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
String all = rs.getString("*");
```

you have to provide the column name in the [getString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) method. Presently it assumes `*` as a column name which is not correct and hence shows an error.

You have to provide the column name in that like this:

```
String all = rs.getString("Column_Name");
```

**EDIT:-**

You may try this if you dont want to write the names of the columns

```
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData(); 
int colCount = md.getColumnCount();  

for (int i = 1; i <= colCount ; i++){  
String col_name = md.getColumnName(i);  
System.out.println(col_name);  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the following generic approach:

```
c = getConnection();
st = c.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from MY_TABLE");

ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

while(rs.next()) {
    for(int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
        Object object = rs.getObject(columnIndex);
        System.out.printf("%s, ", object == null ? "NULL" : object.toString());
    }
    System.out.printf("%n");
}
```

It gets the [Metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) from the the returned Resultset to determine the number of columns the result set contains and does a simple iteration. This works even if your SQL is `select col1, col2 from MY_TABLE`. In such a case `columnCount` would be `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify `*` to get the value. For every column your query returns and you wish to print out, specify either:

```
 String all = rs.getString("your_column_name");
```

or:

```
 String all = rs.getString(i);
```

where "i" is the order of the printed column in the output of your query

Answer (score 0):

The `*` in your query means select all the columns of the table.

But after executing the query, your result will have all the name of the columns.
So to access a result, you have to do:

```
String a_column_value = rs.getString("a_column_name");
```